# Найти повторяющуюся последовательность в подстроке

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, текст, подстрока

Всем привет. Задача такова - найти самую длинную повторяющуюся последовательность в исходной подстроке.
Задач элементарно решается перебором. Но хочется одолеть её регулярными выражениями.
**Текущий код:**

```py
import re

def repeat_inside(text):
    m = re.findall(r'((\w+)\2+)', text)
    print('исходный текст = {}, результат поиска = {}'.format(text, m[0][0]))
    return m[0][0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert repeat_inside('aabbff') == 'aa'
    assert repeat_inside('aaaaa') == 'aaaaa'
    assert repeat_inside('aababcc') == 'abab'
    assert repeat_inside('abc') == ''
    assert repeat_inside('abcabcabab') == 'abcabc'
```

**Результат выполнения:**

```py
исходный текст = aabbff, результат поиска = aa
исходный текст = aaaaa, результат поиска = aaaaa
исходный текст = aababcc, результат поиска = aa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/.../main.py", line 12, in <module>
    assert repeat_inside('aababcc') == 'abab'
AssertionError
```

Пробовал менять регулярное выражение на \w?((\w+)\2+). Это решает проблему с aababcc. Но ломает другие тесты. Есть ли у кого-то идеи? Можно без ответа, просто подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону рыть.

Comment: `repeat_inside('aaaaa') == 'aaaaa'` - это неправильно. Хотя стоп, что ты вообще ищешь? Получается, не саму строку? В любом случае, так нельзя.

Comment: С помощью регулярных выражений невозможно найти самую длинную или самую короткую последовательность/совпадение. Это делается элементарно с помощью средств языка программирования после поиска всех совпадений.


Если вам показалось, что проблему могут решить жадные или нежадные квантификаторы, то это неправда, так как эти операторы всего лишь влияют на то, будет ли правая граница совпадения как можно ближе или как можно дальше от начала совпадения.

Comment: @Qwertiy В этом и суть, что я ищу ПОДстроку в строке, в которой повторяются элементы. В тестировании рассматриваются все случаи, например, вся строка является подстрокой или строка пустая. Как раз в "ааааа" есть элемент "а", который повторяется 5 раз и это будет считаться самой длиной подстрокой строки.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew спасибо за объяснение. А каким путём можно пойти, кроме брутфорса строки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашёл решение. Необходимо было использовать lookahead assertion (?=...). Итоговое регулярное выражение:

```py
re.findall(r'(?=((.+?)\2+))', text)
```

Итоговый код:

```py
import re

def repeat_inside(text):
    match = re.findall(r'(?=((.+?)\2+))', text)
    return max((x[0] for x in match), key=len, default='')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert repeat_inside('aaaaa') == 'aaaaa', "First"
    assert repeat_inside('aabbff') == 'aa', "Second"
    assert repeat_inside('aababcc') == 'abab', "Third"
    assert repeat_inside('abc') == '', "Forth"
    assert repeat_inside('abcabcabab') == 'abcabc', "Fifth"
```