# re.findall возвращает часть найденного текста при поиске повторяющихся фрагментов строки

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Допустим, есть строка `ABC abcabc fff abcabcabc`.

Возможно ли с помощью регулярного выражения получить список вида `[ABC, abcabc, abcabcabc]`?

Я сделал так:

```
re.findall(r"(abc)+", str)
```

Но результат другой :(

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/998636/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5

Comment: Но мне же не самую длинную, мне надо все)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

При использовании метода `re.findall` с регулярным выражением, содержащим *захватывающую подмаску*, результатом будет *список строк* (или список кортежей строк, если таких подмасок больше одной). Так как захватывающая подмаска в данном выражении повторяется (с помощью квантификатора `+`, но и в любом другом случае, например, `{0,10}`, `*`, результат будет похожий), в буфере памяти первой подмаски сохранится только последнее захваченное значение.

Т.е. `re.findall(r'(abc)+', 'abcabcabc')` вернёт только `abc` и список длиной в 1 элемент.

Вы можете использовать *незахватывающую подмаску*, `(?:...)`:

```
import re
text = 'ABC abcabc fff abcabcabc'
print( re.findall(r'(?:abc)+', text, flags=re.I) )
# => ['ABC', 'abcabc', 'abcabcabc']
```

См. [пример работы программы](https://ideone.com/TnAnd7). Обратите внимание на `flags=re.I`, флаг регистронезависимого поиска.

В других случаях, если вы не можете заменить захватывающие подмаски на незахватывающие, например, если вы используете обратные ссылки для поиска повторяющихся шаблонов ([`r'(.)\1{2,}'`](https://regex101.com/r/R06Ypt/1)), тогда вам придётся использовать `re.finditer`:

```
[m.group() for m in re.finditer(r'(abc)+', text, flags=re.I)]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, за подробный ответ!!